# batch: comparing filenames and renaming

Tags: batch-file

I just started on a bigger project that mainly consists of analyzing data and finding algorithms in order to maintain a certain function of a system.

In order to get started I got a bunch of recorded data that, unfortunately, is not consistent when it comes to naming. Normally all files (all in one folder) should start with `SPY.SPYNODE.SIDE` and then go on with the specific names for each values or variables. However, the data logger messed it up a couple of times and gives weird names like `SP0E1A~1.csv` (all files are .csv-files).

An that's when I figured in stead of renaming a couple of thousand files manually I could "easily" use a simple batch file to do that job for name. And that's exactly when I started to go crazy :-)

So far I came up with the following:

```
FOR /R %%i in (%CD%) DO (
  set file1=%%i
  if not %file1%=="SPY.SPYNODE.SIDE" DO (
  set /p "filename" < %file1%
  rename %file1% %filename%
  )
)
```

So what I want it to do is this (in pseudo code)

```
look through the whole folder and every file
    save the filename in variable file1
    if file1 partially equals SPY.SPYNODE.SIDE
        open the file and save the first line (which contains the correct name of the file) in variable filename
        rename the file with the correct filename
```

But so far it doesn't really work and I don't know why.

How should I proceed?

Comment: If this is Windows (seems like it is) go for Powershell or WSH (Windows Scripting Host) via VBScript or JScript. The former is preinstalled since Vista (IIRC), the latter is available on any sensible Windows version. These environments are much much more powerful than `cmd.exe`. [One example](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?504189-Rename-multiple-files-in-a-folder&s=672f44a31da84b872b13eae691ec8167&p=3111195&viewfull=1#post3111195).

Comment: How do SP0E1A~1 partially equal SPY.SPYNODE.SIDE? And, how the first line of file is ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what it is and isn't doing correctly, so I'll have to guess.

I didn't thoroughly test the script (by creating a filesystem tree like you've described), but this modification seems likely to work:

```
FOR /R %%i in (*) DO (
  IF NOT "%%~nxi"=="SPY.SPYNODE.SIDE" DO (
    SET /P filename= < "%%~i"
    RENAME "%%~i" "%filename%"
  )
)
```

You didn't say why it was important to save the file name in another variable, so I removed that part.

`FOR /R` walks the current directory if you don't give it one, so I removed that part. The expression in parens is a pattern to match (though, in my experience, it **must** include a wildcard, or it will attempt to append the expression to the variable for every file it finds).

`%%~nxi` gives you just the filename and extension. Otherwise, you get the complete path to the file, and the equality comparison will fail for any file not in the CWD.

The `set /p` expression needed an equals (=) after the variable name, and the variable name cannot be in quotes. (They shouldn't be needed, since variable names cannot have spaces or special characters in them.)

If the file name in the special file (SPY.SPYNODE.SIDE) is an absolute path, the rename command will likely fail. You would have to "move" the file instead of renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
PUSHD \sourcedir
FOR /R %%i in (*.csv) DO (
 ECHO %%i|FIND /i "spy.spynode.side" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  SET renme=Y
  FOR /f "delims=" %%r IN ('TYPE "%%i"') DO IF DEFINED renme SET "renme="&REN "%%i" "%%r.csv"
 )
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

This should work for you.

Your problem is that in a compound statement (like the `FOR`) a `%var%` is replaced at parse time by the contents of the variable AT PARSE TIME - and that goes for the entire statement from the `FOR` keyword through to the closing parenthesis.

There ARE simple ways of getting around this (the "delayed expansion" problem - many, many SO items) but in this case, it's not required.

First, the `PUSHD` switches to the required diectory, then the `FOR/R` grabs all of the `.CSV` filenames and applies them to `%%i` in turn.

`ECHO`ing `%%i` into `FIND` for your required string (`/i`=case-insensitive) will set `ERRORLEVEL` to 0 if found; non-zero otherwise. The `>nul` suppresses echoing the result of the `FIND`.

The format `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` is TRUE if `ERRORLEVEL` is 1 or greater, and `ERRORLEVEL` is set by the `FIND`. Note that `IF %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1` will NOT work here because `%errorlevel%` would be replaced by the PARSE-TIME value of `ERRORLEVEL` and thus be invariant.

Setting `renme` to Y (well, any value would do) ensures that it **IS** defined for the first line read from the file whose name is conveniently in `%%i` but `renme` is then cleared and is therefore no longer `DEFINED` hence the `REN` command will only be executed for the first line.

I'm not sure whether you wanted to add the `.csv` to the filename-read or no. Remove if not required, obviously.